# Appengine Blobstore - How to get responses cached?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, blobstore

I tried the following but my browser (Chrome) is not caching:

```
    Calendar future = Calendar.getInstance();
    future.add(Calendar.YEAR, +1);
    rsp.setDateHeader("Expires", future.getTimeInMillis());
    rsp.setHeader("Cache-control", "max-age=30");
    blobstore_service.serve(blob_key, http_servlet_response);
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=30
Content-Length:92036
Content-Type:image/jpeg; name="foo.jpg"
Date:Sun, 20 Feb 2011 08:09:20 GMT
Expires:Mon, 20 Feb 2012 08:09:20 GMT
Server:Google Frontend
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does the file appear in the cache? Entering `about:cache` as the location shows all cached files. You can find out what meta-data they're stored with by clicking on individual files there. Maybe that gives you a hint.

Comment: Thank you meyertee for suggesting the tool I should use to debug my problem.  The page was indeed being cached -- I was just wrong in assuming that accessing it again by pasting the URL in Chrome would fetch from cache; it does not.  The cache is used only if I access the URL through a link on another page, or, for images, if I embed the images in a page and refresh the page.  The images are then fetched from the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page was indeed being cached -- I was just wrong in assuming that accessing it again by pasting the URL in Chrome would fetch from cache; it does not.  The cache is used only if the URL is accessed through a link on another page, or, for images, if they are embedded in another page.